# Rotate the contents of the JSON as table

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

If the JSON is [1,2,3,4], the table rotated clockwise once. in the second example, 5 is fixed and all the other numbers have rotated clockwise one time. The system should give the following output and print as a JSON.

```
input            output

1  2              3  1
           ->
3  4              4  2


input              output

1  2  3            4  1  2
           ->
4  5  6            7  5  3

7  8  9            8  9  6
```

How I can achieve this in javascript/typescript ?

please let me know if any clarification is needed or if you feel something is missing.

Thanks folks.

Comment: Please see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Is the array always guaranteed to have a perfect square number of elements?  When you "rotate" a square of length four or more, what do you do about the fact that the outer "rings" will take longer to rotate back into place than the inner rings?  Like, look at [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqvYRW).  Is that really what you want?

Comment: @jcalz, thanks a lot. I am looking for this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a two-dimensional rectangular array, whereas your input seems to be a one-dimensional array.  It's easy enough to "chunk" a 1D array into a 2D array:

```
const chunk = <T,>(arr: T[], size: number): T[][] =>
  Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) },
    (_, i) => arr.slice(i * size, (i + 1) * size));
```

And let's see that in action; starting with an array of 25 elements:

```
const width = 5;
const origArray = Array.from({ length: width * width }, (_, i) => (i + 1));
console.log(origArray); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
// 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
```

The chunked version has 5 elements, each with 5 elements:

```
const chunkedArr = chunk(origArray, width);
console.log(chunkedArr); // [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
// [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
```

That's not a good way to visualize "rotations" though, so let's display it in 2D:

```
displayArr(chunkedArr); /* "
   1,   2,   3,   4,   5
   6,   7,   8,   9,  10
  11,  12,  13,  14,  15
  16,  17,  18,  19,  20
  21,  22,  23,  24,  25"  */
```

where `displayArr()` is defined as

```
const displayArr = <T,>(arr: T[][]) =>
  console.log("\n" + arr.map(c => c.map(v => String(v).padStart(4))).join("\n"))
```

---

Okay, once we have a two-dimensional array, how do we "rotate" it by one element?  Presumably you move each element by one position (either up, right, down, or left) depending on where in the array it is.  This isn't really rotation as I know it, or at least not rigid rotation.

Instead what you're doing is dividing the array into "rings", and moving each element clockwise in its own ring.  In the above 25-element array, there are three rings.  The outermost ring (I'll call "ring 0") consisting of sixteen elements (1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,25,24,23,22,21,16,11,6), the intermediate ring (I'll call "ring 1") consisting of eight elements (7,8,9,14,19,18,17,12), and the innermost ring (I'll call "ring 2") consisting of one element (13).

Any element in the top row of its ring which is not in the rightmost column of its ring should move right.  Any element in the left column of its ring should then move up.  Any element in the bottom row of its ring should then move left.  And anything left over should move down.  If we can programmatically determine the "ring number" for each element, and whether the element is at the top, right, bottom, or left side of its ring, we can adjust the element index accordingly.

One wrinkle is that when the array has an odd number of rows and an odd number of columns, the innermost ring cannot really move.  If you have a 5-by-7 array, for example, there will be 1-by-3 ring in the middle.  A 1-by-3 ring like "A, B, C" can't really go anywhere.  (I mean, you could come up with some other way of shifting that, like to "C, A, B" or something, but that would be quite different from the other rings.)  So we need to detect if the array has such a "stationary ring" and not move any elements in that ring.

Here's one possible implementation:

```
function rotateClockwise<T>(arr: T[][]) {
  const ret: any[][] = arr.map(c => c.map(v => "")); // blank copy 
  const rows = arr.length;
  if (rows === 0) return ret;
  const cols = arr[0].length;
  if (!arr.every(l => l.length === cols)) throw new Error("Not rectangular");
  const stationaryRing = (rows % 2 !== 0) && (cols % 2 !== 0) ? 
    (Math.min(rows, cols) - 1) / 2 : -1;
  for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    let nr = rows - 1 - r;
    for (let c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      let nc = cols - 1 - c;
      const ring = Math.min(r, nr, c, nc);
      let [rNew, cNew] = [r, c];
      if (ring !== stationaryRing) {
        if (r === ring && nc !== ring) cNew++; // top row moves right (except for rightmost)
        else if (c === ring) rNew--; // left column moves up
        else if (nr === ring) cNew--; // bottom row moves left
        else rNew++; // right column moves down
      }
      ret[rNew][cNew] = arr[r][c];
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

The logic there mirrors the above discussion.  For each element at row `r` and column `c` measured from the top left of the array, you can also compute `nr` and `nc`, the index of the element measured from the bottom right of the array.  The `ring` number is the minimum of these.  If the `ring` is not the stationary ring, then you can check each of the four motion cases.  If `r === ring` then you're on the top.  If `c === ring` then you're on the left.  If `nr === ring` then you're on the bottom.  And if `(nc === ring)` then you're on the right.  I guess I won't belabor the point anymore.

---

Let's see how this works for the above 25-element array:

```
displayArr(rotateClockwise(chunkedArr)); /* 
   6,   1,   2,   3,   4
  11,  12,   7,   8,   5
  16,  17,  13,   9,  10
  21,  18,  19,  14,  15
  22,  23,  24,  25,  20" */
```

Looks good.  The outermost ring has rotated by one, as has the intermediate ring, while the innermost ring has not moved.

Just to be sure this works for different cases, let's try a 5-by-7 array:

```
const chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abc"+
  "defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()_-+=[]{}\\|;:'\",<.>/?`~";

const makeArr = (rows: number, cols: number) =>
  Array.from({ length: rows }, (_, r) => 
    Array.from({ length: cols }, (_, c) => chars.charAt(r * cols + c)));

const arr = makeArr(5, 7);
displayArr(arr); /* "
   A,   B,   C,   D,   E,   F,   G
   H,   I,   J,   K,   L,   M,   N
   O,   P,   Q,   R,   S,   T,   U
   V,   W,   X,   Y,   Z,   0,   1
   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8" */

displayArr(rotateClockwise(arr)); /* "
   H,   A,   B,   C,   D,   E,   F
   O,   P,   I,   J,   K,   L,   G
   V,   W,   Q,   R,   S,   M,   N
   2,   X,   Y,   Z,   0,   T,   U
   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   1" */
```

Also looks good.  You can see that the innermost `Q, R, S` ring didn't move, while the other rings shifted by one element.  You should feel free to play around with different arrays and see how it works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgSwgBwDYEMCeBBATrmAXhgB4AVAGgD4AKdfALhjIG0BddgSiKoFgAoGDFCQQqAKYA6VCADmNAEQAdMApgBqGPVySAtumQ1gPYXoM0AbiYDKUXAjDyLnScnRxb9KDQAsnf5IAViAOiioK-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-ZYJGiWBwViXQASAkCYFiZAsMbHCIDwu8xwfZCP2AMiKMWZYVnSKAQF0ACYCY8RTmoqB2KETi8MXOlvxE5DUJdejGOAuT4CVMB2IAX3Yn4oAXVcOEEul12IbQFxs7dZzMkE3KECy-gBCzgTcqJ+B7YRrniTZiHIag6EYZh2GdCAEAAL3EJgwHolYsU4SpunsvgQTwXAsEkaI0l0GhahgCQESYAd7TghBUCinRKqJa5FhgeKku4EyKFnGgAH1nQQbhJnOCBUAQOCaAQGAACp2sS8RnSmjQvW4OaOvEfxgQEILijgYliAAVmBIKWRQ-KsF6C7MCKkqyoqy4WqYPbiTml7Wu6p4BtvYaRmWzRvRnQKRTEKQZHkM7ZGuuZNJYT1nXVZ0AGZnR8Z1DudAA2Z0AHZnQADmdABOZ1PQ+Un4a9RGvRRr00a9DGvWxr08a9QmvRJjVyY1Sn1Wp9VafVen1UO9cAqC4AQo2cQ4Hy1spfyGhIeu513qBppQekOQjAVmX8ph38WDhhHkdR9G2GdFhmdZ9nObJi2YDhynPWpz1ac9enPVFy3PWZz1Wc9dnPU59VYUt9Vef5wXhdFsX+EQFAMBwfAddCvX8ANuaFFTSmhGpoRaaEemhEO1NmaEVmhHZoROa9D59k9XOXedGmW49tvS5BX228rwO29r0P9gjlu+ZHwuhZHw61FmhYAoTtAsHyxUMiyXIQAKYouNT6XZYzzO9gbcuvRbjUT8LmAfAbpv85gSuYGrmBO6Ebvn978-a7Joem+r4O2+Lr2h75wFiPYuIsR4fDUDNWe-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)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your second example looks the way it does, but it looks  like you want to reshape the one-dimensional array into a two-dimensional matrix, shift a row, and then transpose.

Could you clarify what "shift to the right once" really means?

```js
const reshape = (data, size) =>
  new Array(size[0]).fill(0).map((y, row) =>
    new Array(size[1]).fill(0).map((x, col) =>
      data[row * size[1] + col]));

const shift = (matrix, oldIndex,  newIndex) => {
  const [extracted] = matrix.splice(oldIndex, 1);
  matrix.splice(newIndex, 0, extracted);
  return matrix;
}

const transpose = (matrix) => matrix[0].map((_, col) =>
  matrix.map(row => row[col]));

const print = (matrix) =>
  console.log(matrix.map(col => col.join(' ')).join('\n'));

print(transpose(shift(reshape([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2]), 0, 1)));
print(transpose(shift(reshape([1, 2, 3, 4,  5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 3]), 0, 1)));
```

### Edit

I included a non-TypeScript version of jcalz code linked above.

```js
// Needs to be a perfect square
const arr = [
   1,  2,  3,  4,  5,
   6,  7,  8,  9, 10,
  11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
  16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
  21, 22, 23, 24, 25
];

const format = (matrix) =>
  matrix.map(row => row.map(col =>
    String(col).padStart(4))).join('\n');

const chunk = (arr, size) =>
  Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) }, (_, i) =>
    arr.slice(i * size, (i + 1) * size));

let chunked = chunk(arr, Math.round(Math.sqrt(arr.length)));

console.log(`Original:\n${format(chunked)}`)

for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  const rotated = Array.from({ length: chunked.length }, (_, r) =>
    Array.from({ length: chunked[r].length }));

  const rCenter = (chunked.length - 1) / 2;
  for (let r = 0; r < chunked.length; r++) {
    const dr = r - rCenter;
    const cCenter = (chunked[r].length - 1) / 2;
    for (let c = 0; c < chunked[r].length; c++) {
      const val = chunked[r][c];
      const dc = c - cCenter;
      const ring = Math.max(Math.abs(dr), Math.abs(dc));
      let [rNew, cNew] = [r, c];
      if (ring !== 0) {
        if (dr === -ring && dc !== ring) cNew++; // ➡
        else if (dc === -ring) rNew--;           // ⬆
        else if (dr === ring) cNew--;            // ⬅
        else rNew++;                             // ⬇
      }
      rotated[rNew][cNew] = val;
    }
  }

  console.log(`After ${i} rotations:\n${format(rotated)}`);

  chunked = rotated; // Update
}

console.log('Note that the inner ring is back to start while the outer ring is rotated 180 degrees');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. may be shift to right is a bit confusing, I will change the question a bit. if you see the output table, it has rotated clockwise and 5 remained in the same position. rest all has rotated one time clockwise. @Mr. Polywhirl